# SQL to display number of unread messages... including unread replies

Tags: php, mysql, messaging

I am building a messaging system for a CMS and can not find a way to get the number of unread messages in a message chain.

**I need a way to find out if the main message or any of it's reply messages are unread.**

I have a table called "messages" that has the fields:
id, active[1,0], subject, message, datetime, user_from, user_to, reply, viewed, removed

When a message is read I store that users id comma-delimited in the viewed field:
,3,4,12,

Then to find out if it's viewed I look for the sender's id like this:

```
m.viewed LIKE '%,$user_id,%'
```

I just figure out how to get that logic into this SQL select so that I can see if a parent message should be marked as unread. The following SQL works great and grabs all the messages and the number of replies and orders them by datetime.

```
SELECT m.*, COUNT(*) AS num_replies, MAX(r.datetime) AS max_datetimeunread_replies
FROM directus_messages AS m
LEFT JOIN directus_messages as r
    ON m.id = r.reply
WHERE m.active = '1' 
AND m.removed NOT LIKE '%,$user_id,%' 
GROUP BY m.id
HAVING m.reply = '0' 
ORDER BY datetime DESC, max_datetime DESC
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated... I can't wrap my head around it!

Comment: Check this similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318010/print-hierachical-data-in-a-parent-child-form-unordered-list-php/4318846#4318846

Comment: Side questions: How long are the `viewed` and `removed` fields? What happens when more than 100 users view a message? You really should try normalizing the table than using comma-delimited fields.

Comment: Also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291054/hierarchical-sql-problem

Comment: The CMS is very tightly managed and does not support that many users... so the datatype is just a VARCHAR(255) which can hold more than enough ids. That article was in the right direction... but I don't think it will help me with my current issue. I THINK I just need a a small addition to my SQL query... I'm just not sure where.

Comment: If you think the maximum level of message-reply-reply-...-reply is small, then it can be handled by a decent SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check this article: [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

--EDIT--UPDATE

OK, you only have 1 level of replies so no need for the above.

Try this:

```
SELECT m.*
     , COUNT(*) AS num_replies
     , MAX(r.datetime) AS max_datetime
     , (m.viewed LIKE '%,$user_id,%') 
         AS message_viewed    --shows True or False
     , SUM(r.viewed NOT LIKE '%,$user_id,%')
         AS unread_replies    --shows number of unread replies
FROM directus_messages AS m
  LEFT JOIN directus_messages as r
    ON m.id = r.reply
WHERE m.active = '1' 
  AND m.removed NOT LIKE '%,$user_id,%' 
GROUP BY m.id
HAVING m.reply = '0' 
ORDER BY m.datetime DESC
       , max_datetime DESC
;
```

Comment: @ypercube I forgot to explain, there is only one level of replies per message... there are messages and replies to those messages. You can not reply to a reply.

Comment: Any further advice based on this simplified structure? I see adding another table just to track who has viewed a message to be complicating things. The SQL to see if a message is viewed is straightforward... I just need a way to incorporate it into my existing SELECT.

Comment: The SQL to see if a message has not been viewed by anyone is `viewed = ','` ?

Comment: correct, but i would need to find whether any have been viewed by the current user. I would use the id in the query `m.viewed LIKE '%,$user_id,%'` where $user_id would be a number like 3 searching `viewed` which would contain something like ",2,3,6," if they've viewed it ... or ",2,7,12," if they haven't

Comment: OK. I think i understand what you want.